# Create a suggestion list using typeahead.js and the source is from database

Tags: php, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

How can I make the suggestion list work using typeahead.js and with
database as the source?

Before trying the database code, the fixed source code is working.
But when I tried the database code, the database code does not work.

If possible, please explain why my database code does not work.

Fixed source code:

```
<html>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#citiesInput').typeahead({                               
                name: "suggestion typeahead",
                local: ["italy", "malaysia", "new york", "USA", "England"]
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" class="q typeahead" dir="auto" id="citiesInput" onkeyup="typeahead(this.value)" />
</html>
```

Database code:

```
<html>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#citiesInput').typeahead({                               
                name: "suggestion typeahead",
                remote: "/suggestion.php?q=%QUERY"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" class="q typeahead" dir="auto" id="citiesInput" onkeyup="typeahead(this.value)" />

</html>
```

suggestion.php:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //connect with database
$query = $_GET["q"];
if($query != "")
{
$safequery = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query);
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' OR link LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' LIMIT 4";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($number_of_result > 0) {
    //results found here and display them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //show first 10 results
        $title = $row["title"];
        $link = $row["link"];
        echo "<div id='sugg-search-result'>";
        echo "<a href='$link' id='sugg-title'>" . $title . "</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if you use the search funcionality you will have a lot of info about your problem

Comment: @Leonardo do you have any questions or post in stackoverflow related to my problem? I could not find any.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap+typeahead+remote

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Is there an error? Does the PHP code ever run?

Comment: I mean the suggestion list does not work like the examples for typeahead. I want the suggestion list has suggestion words completing the keywords users type just like google.

Comment: When you say a car "doesn't work" it could mean many things. Maybe the battery is dead. Maybe it ran out of gas. Maybe the key is not in the ignition. If you tell the mechanic, "Well, the car says 'Fuel Empty'" then the mechanic can tell you that you need to put gas in your car to fix it. Now, in order to help you, we need to know more than "It doesn't work". Does your PHP code ever run? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @ChrisLava When a user types something like `goo`, I want the suggestion `gle` appears behind the `goo`. This is what I want. I find that `typeahead` has this feature so I plan to use it. But after running the `database` code, this feature does not appear. And I have a database with all the suggestions. I want the suggestion comes from this database. I have type a code (`database` code) ready. Can you please check what's wrong?

Comment: @ChrisLava Can you please help me?

Comment: @HFial1964 I know how you want it to work. I understand and know what typeahead is. I've used it. What I want to know is what symptoms you have. Do you get 0 suggestions? Do you get the wrong suggestions? Do you get an error when you run the code? Does the typeahead function have trouble locating your PHP script? I am asking for more information. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 things wrong.

1) You need to specify the remote url (the [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#remote) says it is required) **UPDATE** Seems that you can just set remote to the url. But I do see that they use single-quotes, where you are using double-quotes. Don't know if that matters.

2) Your php class needs to return valid JSON. You are returning html.

**Database**

```
<html>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#citiesInput').typeahead({                               
                name: 'suggestion-typeahead',
                remote: {
                    url: '/suggestion.php?q=%QUERY',
                    datatype: 'json'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" class="q typeahead" dir="auto" id="citiesInput" onkeyup="typeahead(this.value)" />

</html>
```

**Suggestion.php**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //connect with database
$query = $_GET["q"];
if($query != "")
{
$safequery = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query);
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '" . $safequery . "%' LIMIT 4";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$arr = array();

$number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($number_of_result > 0) {
    //results found here and display them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //show first 10 results
        //add $title to an array which you will call json_encode(arr) on.
        $arr[] = $row["title"];
        }
    }
}

$json = json_encode($arr);
print_r($json);
?>
```

### NOTE

I see that your suggestions.php file was returning the title and it's link with the html. Typeahead is supposed to return a list of strings. Once the user selects one of the suggested words, then you should lookup the link for that word.

Comment: I have problems with the suggestion.php code you gave me. After I run that code, I receive `["Google", "Gmail", "Google Maps"]` at the suggestion box. Can you help me to fix it until the suggestions are line by line?

Comment: @HFial1964 you need to change your query. I have updated my answer to be this: `"SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' LIMIT 4"` That will return suggestions where only the title matches, instead of the link and keyword also. Try that.

Comment: Actually, remove the % from the beginning of $safequery. Otherwise, typing "o" will return every word that has an "o" in it. So your query has to look like this: `"SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '" . $safequery . "%' LIMIT 4"` I updated my answer to include this. Try it, @HFial1964

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: @HFial1964 Can you add this: `datatype: 'json'` after the remote url? I updated my answer.

Comment: @HFial1964 Can you remove the whitespace from the typeahead name? In all the examples I've seen, I have never seen whitespace. Can you add a dash or underscore? I updated my answer.

Comment: No suggestions are coming out

Comment: @HFial1964, please try the change I made in the php file. Don't use `echo`, use `print_r($json);` and let me know if that works.

Comment: I have found the solution for **suggestion.php**: [link](http://pastebin.com/L6aji4VE)

Comment: But the suggestions are not becoming one by one that you can select them. They are just a list of text and when you press them, the whole list will disappear. How can I make **typeahead.js** work in this situation?